# How I can get a text from user with multi style in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-text

I have a problem with text in flutter. First I want to display an image.

[image]

I want to build that bottom option to take text from users with multi styles that users choose. So I have two problems.

First, How I can do this?
Second, How I can display this text with styles that the user chooses in my app?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You either build this UI on your own with all the logic (change alignment, fontsize, fonttype, etc. dynamicly). For this you have to save all the selected config and apply it on the ui.

Or the easier option (imo): Use a predefined editor like this one https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_quill